# Linear transformations, $R^5,R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a Linear Transformation $T : R^5 \rightarrow R^4 $ that its $KerT$ is $KerT = \{(
x,y,z,t,w) \in R^5 | x = 2y ,and, z = 2t = 3w\}$

Well, I tried to prove that by first saying :
$KerT = \{2y,y,2t,t,w\}$ and $x=2,y=1,z=6,t=3,w=2$ Thus

$KerT = Sp\{2,1,6,3,2\} $Thus $dimKerT = 1
$

Well, to show that it just a linear transformation from $R^5$ to $R^4$ with that given $KerT$ I need to first find a base in $R^5$, so I did:

$B = \{(2,1,6,3,2),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)\}$
So B is a base in R^5 now.

Well, now it's still not enough so I tried to define $ImT$ and use $ImT = \{T(v1),...,T(v_n)\}$ to prove it's linear transformation.
So I took ImT like that

$T(2,1,6,3,2) = (0,0,0,0,0)$ It's obviously true because $Ker(2,1,6,3,2)= (0,0,0,0,0)$
And then, defining:
$T(0,1,0,0,0) = (1,1,1,1,1)$

$T(0,0,1,0,0) = (2,4,5,6,7)$

$T(0,0,0,1,0) = (3,5,6,7,8)$

$T(0,0,0,0,1) = (4,6,7,8,9)$

Does it prove that $T : R^5 \rightarrow R^4 $ is a Linear Transformation when $KerT = \{(
x,y,z,t,w) \in R^5 | x = 2y ,and, z = 2t = 3w\}$?

If not, is it even possible to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

So we want a linear map $T\colon\Bbb R^5\to\Bbb R^4$ whose kernel is spanned by the three vectors $(2,1,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,2,1,0)$, and $(0,0,3,0,1)$. If we find the orthogonal complement of that three-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^5$, that will give us the row space of the standard matrix of $T$.

To do this we consider the matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix};$$
by standard algorithms, we find that $\ker A = \operatorname{Span}\big((-1,2,0,0,0), (0,0,1,-2,-3)\big)$. (To be sure, note that $\dim\ker A = 5 - \operatorname{rank} A = 2$, and each of these vectors is orthogonal to all the rows of $A$, hence in the kernel.) So any $4\times 5$ matrix whose rows are linear combinations of those two vectors will do.

Comment: I didn't understand how you proved that it's Linear transformation, and also how did you find $ \{(−1,2,0,0,0),(0,0,1,−2,−3)\} $  I thought about taking these 3 vectors $(2,1,0,0,0)$ , $(0,0,2,1,0)$ , $(0,0,3,0,1)$ putting on a matrix, getting a base to $KerT$ which is $(2,1,0,0,0)$ , $(0,0,2,1,0)$ , $(0,0,0,-3,2)$ adding vectors $e2,e5$ to make it $R^5$, but then I still need to show something else for it to be a linear transformation (which I don't know what else I need to prove) Help? :(

Comment: You will write down a matrix with the desired $\ker$, and any matrix represents a linear map :) No, you want to think geometrically. The key thing is that the kernel is the orthogonal complement of the subspace of $\Bbb R^5$ spanned by the rows. And to find the orthogonal complement, I used this same fact: I made a matrix with my $3$ vectors as rows and found its kernel.

Comment: I don't understand you, My math-English isn't that good and you're using words I don't know how to refer to my studying on Hebrew language, but I did take those 3 vectors and got to $(2,1,0,0,0)  , (0,0,2,1,0)  , (0,0,0,−3,2)$ which is a base of $kerT$

Comment: Then I added to standard vectors $e2,e5$ to $KerT$ Base, and got a base in R^5.

Comment: @Ilan: I've edited a bit. OK, you *can* define a linear map by specifying that $T$ sends the three vectors in $\ker T$ to $0$ and your other two basis vectors to arbitrary vectors in $\Bbb R^4$. My way is much easier, though :P It does require understanding some geometry, which not all courses teach.

Comment: How did you find $((−1,2,0,0,0),(0,0,1,−2,−3)$? I'm feeling stupid and confused :(

Comment: You can do it by checking orthogonality. But the reduced echelon form of $A$ is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1/2 & 0 &0&0\\0&0&1&0&1/3\\0&0&0&1&-2/3\end{bmatrix},$$ and we get a basis for the kernel by setting the free variables $x_2$ and $x_5$ equal to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ respectively.

Comment: That is exactly what I said, and u mean x2,x5 equal to (0,1,0,0,0), (0,0,0,0,1) respectively? And then, I still don't get it how you found the 2 vetors $(−1,2,0,0,0),(0,0,1,−2,−3)$

Comment: I guess you haven't learned how to solve linear equations using echelon form of matrices? :( This means the equations $Ax=0$ can be rewritten as $x_1+\frac12 x_2=0$, $x_3+\frac13x_5=0$, $x_4-\frac23x_5=0$. Now solve!!

Comment: Alright, and last question then, why if I find a matrix in $R^4$ which is a span of those 2 vectors $(1,2,0,0,0),(0,0,1,−2,−3)$ makes it a linear transformation?

Comment: You mean a matrix with 4 rows ... Because for any $m\times n$ matrix $B$, $T(x)=Bx$ defines a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$. This is a standard fact and, if you don't know it, you should write out a proof! Good luck!